# composer on the cpanel v68.0.29

Tags: composer-php, cpanel, whm

Server running WHM/cPanel v68. As composer is now included globally with cpanel, I'am login SSH as a cpanel user and try to use composer, but nothing happens:

```
host@host [~]# composer --help

host@host [~]# composer diagnose

host@host [~]#
```

on another server with the same version of the Cpanel and CloudLinux, it's all right. What could be the reason? The version of php set to 7.1 with PHP Selector. Directive

```
allow_url_fopen On
```

are chosen in [CPanel (as reccomended in documentation).](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Set+Up+%28PHP%29+Composer#HowtoSetUp(PHP)Composer-RequiredPHPmodules)

Unfortunately for the first time I try to use a Composer, I do not understand what it needs.

Update:

## composer -V

Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer on line 23

Answer (score 0):

The error that you're seeing at the bottom -

Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer on line 23

.. this means that the phar PHP extension is not loaded. If your cPanel is hosted on a CloudLinux environment you can see if you can enable it from

```
cPanel -> Select PHP Version -> Enable Extension
```

if not - you need to contact your hosting provider to see if they can enable it for you.